# unable to solve input field issue while entering the values using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have an input field for entering messages or some values, but the problem is - whatever i type, it is showing very slowly, if a user types anything then he/ she wants to see their messages accordingly but i dont know why it is taking time. Is there any way to make input field to work accordingly the way we type (speed)? While i console the onchange, it is working great but not in UI. In UI, its taking time.

Can anybody please help me in this?

```
handleMessage = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

 <Input
              placeholder="Enter a Message"
              disableUnderline
              name="msg"
              value={this.state.msg}
              onChange={this.handleMessage}
            />
```

Can anyone please help me in this ?

Comment: There is no problem with your code I think. It's maybe only in your computer, maybe some lack of memory... check the processes

Comment: I ran through the linked sandbox, and didn't detect any slowness.

Comment: @FábioBCSouza - could you please compare enter input field with the console? even my friends also getting the input field bit lagy

Comment: It's clearly real-time

Answer (score 0):

Please export your *Data* like this.

```js
export default withStyles(styles)(React.memo(Data));
```

Please let me know if it does not work.
Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-hill-w5t7b)

Comment: This works okay... But still bit lagging compared to previous one (my query sanbox)